# Dropdown control from system settings

Tags: c#, xaml, drop-down-menu, user-controls, windows-phone

In windows phone settings in several paces presented very interesting control:
[image]

What is the name of this control? Where can I find this control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a ListPicker. Not part of the standard controls, but part of the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) (and can be found on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit/) also)

Comment: Yes, you are right. One more question before accepting you answer. Is possible to enable `SelectionMode="Multiple"` but save UI behavior as for `SelectionMode="Single"`?

Comment: Not sure out of the box, but it provides UI templates for both modes so you can customize manually